# Changing Main Viewing Area

Tags: c#, wpf, contentcontrol

I'm wondering how to go about creating different views in the main window when a button is pressed. I'm not sure of the correct terminology, so that has hampered my google fu.

I'm thinking that the main viewing area would be a content control, that I could change when a event happens. I made a small drawing to help illustrate my idea / thought.

Any input will be appreciated. Thanks!
[image: Crude Mockup]

Comment: Usually that is called Master-Detail architecture as far as i know. I would not use events but selection and [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Comment: Looks exactly like a TabControl with TabStripPlacement="Left". See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabcontrol.tabstripplacement.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be really easy  to implement this senario using MVVM approach....

Make a ViewModel for you MainView. Then Define Properties of the ViewModels of your UserControls

For Example You have Two UserControl as `FirstView` and `SecondView` then make a properties in your viewmodels as `ViewToLoadProperty` of the type ViewModel (usually called as ViewModelBase)

Set bindings as

```
        <!--  Panel For Hosting UserControls  -->
        <Border Grid.Column="2">
            <ContentControl Name="userControlContentControl"
                            Content="{Binding Path=ViewToLoadProperty,
                                              }">
                <ContentControl.Resources>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelLayer:FirstViewModel}">
                        <ViewLayer:FirstView/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModelLayer:SecondViewModel}">
                        <ViewLayer:SecondView />
                    </DataTemplate>
                                        </ContentControl.Resources>
            </ContentControl>
        </Border>
        <!--  Panel For Hosting UserControls  -->
```

Then  when you click the button Use a command to set the respective ViewModel Intance to this(ViewToLoadProperty) property...(Use `RelayCommannds` or something like it)

`DataTempates` would do the rest of the job by selecting the right View according to the right type of ViewModel

YOu can use MVVMLight toolkit if you are implementing MVVM Pattern.. :)

Comment: I had the other answer and I still gave you a +1.  I need to learn MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

On the right you could have a frame.  Then the button would bind a different page or user control to the content of that frame.